# Automated form submission to an external script

Tags: php, forms, curl

got a question and I'm not really sure about it, so I thought I'd ask.

One of the pages on my server contains an ordinary HTML form, that is designed to contact an external script for its form submission.

If I open the page, enter the information in the fields manually, and hit "Process", the external script will, naturally, record my own IP address as a visitor.

What IP address will it record if I automate the form submission by using a server-side method, such as cURL? Does it record the server's IP address, since the server is sending an automated request to the script, or does it record the client's IP address, as usual?

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, it will record the address it sees in the request, which depends on how routing on your server is set up.
If you're sending the request to localhost - then it will actually record localhost (127.0.0.1) rather than the server`s external IP even.

If your request originates by some visitor surfing the web, you have multiple options of keeping track:

1. Use a standard `X-Forwarded-For` header in your sub-request and track it as you would track any proxied request. (Check if `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` is passed and use that as a real address, otherwise fallback to `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`).
2. Pass the original IP as some custom parameter and track that instead of `REMOTE_ADDR` when request comes from certain source (eg from localhost).